# Formula to generate random enemies

Tags: random

In my endless game i need to generate random enemies for each "level".

For each level i need to generate the total number of enemies that have to be spawn, and spawn them a few at a time. When they are finished, go to next level and repeat calculation.

So, from the current level (that i know, it's a number, 1,2,3..), i need to generate:

1) A random number indicating the TOTAL number of enemies for this level

2) A random number indicating how many enemies "in this very moment" i have to spawn (extract from the total list) from the total

3) Since i need spawn enemies a little at a time, i need to generate a random number indicating this time

All of these values should increase the difficulty according to the current level.

This is my approach, but if you have other solutions it's ok.

Actually i don't know which formulas i could use.

This is my code (not random):

```
// if there are no enemies to be spawn...
    if(enemiesToSpawn.size == 0) {
        gameManager.incrementLevel();
        // generate the enemies according to the current level --> put them into enemiesToSpawn
        generateEnemies();
        // reset timeAccumulator
        timeAccumulator = 0f;
        // initialize target time
        targetTime = 2;
    }
    // there are enemies to be spawn...
    else if(enemiesToSpawn.size != 0){
        // increment accumulator
        timeAccumulator += delta;

        // extract enemies and add them to the stage
        if(timeAccumulator >= targetTime) {
            int amount = 1; // should be random
            Array<BaseEnemy> enemies = extractEnemies(amount); // extract enemies from enemiesToSpawn
            for(BaseEnemy enemy: enemies) {
                EntityManager.addEnemy(enemy, gameTable); // add enemies to the stage
            }

            // reset accumulator
            timeAccumulator = 0f;
            // reset target time (should be random)
            targetTime = 10;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want hard cap on how many enemies are alive at a time?

Comment: I need to generate that number randomly too. I do that in the "generateEnemies()" method. Actually that number is fixed to 8. Anyway, i would increment that number infinitely.

Comment: Almost nothing. I don't know if there is a best way/known way to do that. I tried something like, int totalEnemies = (int)(Math.random() * (currentLevel * some_factor)) + 2. I need to randomize the amount and the targetTime too...

Comment: You can always trying throwing random equations into this https://www.desmos.com/calculator until you get something that looks good to you.

Comment: Valve uses an AI director in their game Left4Dead: http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2009/ai_systems_of_l4d_mike_booth.pdf. The linked presentation has a chapter about how the AI Director decides when to spawn enemies (and how much).